# Magento 2:Msrp in list page

Tags: product, magento-2.1, attribute-set, product-prices, msrp

I have extended the phtml file

```
/vendor/magento/module-catalog/templates/product/price/amount/default.phtml`.
```

I want to get the **msrp price** and **attribute set id** in the extended template in both list page and view page.

I have used the following code

```
<?php $product = $this->helper('Company\Module\Helper\Data')->getCurrentProduct();?>
<?php $msrp = $product->getMsrp();?>
<?php $attributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();?>
```

In view page it is working fine. But in list page getting error as `'Call to a member function getMsrp() is null`'.

Answer (score 0):

The error provided sounds very unfamiliar. It should either say:

1. Call to a member function getMsrp() on null

or

2. Methond getMsrp() is undefined

I am very tempted to say that the error you got is the first example (**on null** instead of **is null**). A strong reason for this is that on a magento product a get method converts to `getData()` which is always defined. For example `getMsrp()` is equal to `getData('msrp)` and even if msrp attribute is not loaded it should return an empty string.

Moving forward you should check your `getCurrentProduct()` method and see why it's returning a null product